# Unable to connect wifi on ubuntu 16.04 from my asus tp 200s

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 16.04, asus

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04 on an asus tp200s and the wifi is not working, it cannot even see networks.

my output of `lspci` is:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22cc (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
```

And my output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:2231]
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: What is the output of this command: `iwlist wlan0 scan` ?

Comment: The output is:wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

Comment: What about this command: `nmcli dev wifi list`

Comment: nmcli dev wifi list did not output anything

Comment: What is displayed when you click on wireless icon on top right of the screen in Wi-Fi Network section ? (any text like Hardware is disabled or Device not managed)

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `dmesg | grep ath`